# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Document> has no method 'load'

Tags: javascript

guys,im having trouble reading xml files using javascript, plz help me

here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
xmlDoc.load("myfile.xml");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

im using win7 ,I've used opera 12,the latest chorme, firefox 14,IE9,safari 5(windows verison),and none of them works, and  google chorme gives me this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Document> has no method 'load'
```

i dont know whats wrong here, thx in advance

Comment: what are you trying to do here

Comment: Document object does not have this method. Do you want to load and parse XML?

Comment: *"i dont know whats wrong here"*: Apparently a `Document` object does not have a `load` method (and hence you cannot call it).

Comment: reading xml using javascript

Comment: @FelixKling well who'da thunk it...

Comment: but i've seen this scriptlet on a book

Comment: As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.load) it is part of it is part of an old W3C dom spec, thet might have removed it since it is not present in the document object now. You need to use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) to load the data

Answer (score 0):

> guys,im having trouble reading xml files using javascript

Lots of google results for loading xml files dynamically using javascript (cf. AJAX). But to help you get started in the right direction, consider

```
// Caveat: IE 5 and IE 6 must do:
// var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","myfile.xml",false);  // the third param sets async=false
xmlhttp.send();
var xmldata = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

EDIT: the above was from my AJAX notes, see [the w3 tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) on the topic for the walk-through version.